# List all Files from a Directory that match a File Mask (a.k.a Pattern or Glob)

Tags: java, file-io, nio, directorystream

I want to list **all files** in a **directory and subdirectories** within that directory that match a **file mask**.

For example "M:\SOURCE\*.doc" while SOURCE may look like this:

```
|-- SOURCE
|   |-- Folder1
|   |   |-- File1.doc
|   |   |-- File1.txt
|   |-- File2.doc
|   |-- File3.xml
```

Should return File1.doc and File2.doc.

Initially, I use a **DirectoryStream**, because that already makes some checks for the mask/glob syntax as well as being able to use it for filtering as this **ISN'T** just some regex but an actual file mask that a regular user finds easier to understand

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(path, mask);
```

The problem is a DirectoryStream only checks the immediate path directory that you provide and **not it's subdirectories**

**THEN** comes a "flattening" method with **Files.walk** which is in fact able to look through all of the subdirectories, problem is, it DOES NOT provide with the possibility to "filter" by a File Mask the same way that a DirectoryStream does

```
Files.walk(path, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

So I'm stuck, unable to combine the best of both methods here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might have solved my own question with the insight received here and other questions mentioning the `PathMatcher` object

```
final PathMatcher maskMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
                  .getPathMatcher("glob:" + mask);

final List<Path> matchedFiles = Files.walk(path)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

final List<Path> filesToRemove = new ArrayList<>(matchedFiles.size());

matchedFiles.forEach(foundPath -> {
            if (!maskMatcher.matches(foundPath.getFileName()) || Files.isDirectory(foundPath)) {
              filesToRemove.add(foundPath);
            }
          });

 matchedFiles.removeAll(filesToRemove);
```

So basically `.getPathMatcher("glob:" + mask);` is the same thing that the **DirectoryStream** was doing to filter the files

All I have to do now after that is filtering the list of paths that I get with **Files.walk** by removing the elements that do not match my PathMatcher and are not of type File

Answer (score 3):

You can use also custom `FileVisitor` [1], with combination of `PathMatcher` [2], which works perfectly with GLOBs.

Code might look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(getFiles(Paths.get("/tmp/SOURCE"), "*.doc"));
}

public static List<Path> getFiles(final Path directory, final String glob) throws IOException {
    final var docFileVisitor = new GlobFileVisitor(glob);
    Files.walkFileTree(directory, docFileVisitor);

    return docFileVisitor.getMatchedFiles();
}

public static class GlobFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    private final PathMatcher pathMatcher;
    private List<Path> matchedFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    public GlobFileVisitor(final String glob) {
        this.pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + glob);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes basicFileAttributes) throws IOException {
        if (pathMatcher.matches(path.getFileName())) {
            matchedFiles.add(path);
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public List<Path> getMatchedFiles() {
        return matchedFiles;
    }
}
```

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html

[2] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use common Stream `filter` to retrieve the filtered file names from `Files.walk` using `String::matches` with appropriate regular expression:

```java
final String SOURCE_DIR = "test";

Files.walk(Paths.get(SOURCE_DIR));
     .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().matches(".*\\.docx?"))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
test\level01\level11\test.doc
test\level02\test-level2.doc
test\t1.doc
test\t3.docx
```

Input directory structure:

```
│   t1.doc
│   t2.txt
│   t3.docx
│   t4.bin
│
├───level01
│   │   test.do
│   │
│   └───level11
│           test.doc
│
└───level02
        test-level2.doc
```

---

**Update**

A recursive solution is possible using `newDirectoryStream` however it needs to be converted into Stream:

```java
static Stream<Path> readFilesByMaskRecursively(Path start, String mask) {
        
    List<Stream<Path>> sub = new ArrayList<>();
        
    try {
        sub.add(StreamSupport.stream( // read files by mask in current dir
                Files.newDirectoryStream(start, mask).spliterator(), false));
            
        Files.newDirectoryStream(start, (path) -> path.toFile().isDirectory())
             .forEach(path -> sub.add(recursive(path, mask)));
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
        
    return sub.stream().flatMap(s -> s); // convert to Stream<Path>
}

// test
readFilesByMaskRecursively(Paths.get(SOURCE_DIR), "*.doc*")
             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
test\t1.doc
test\t3.docx
test\level01\level11\test.doc
test\level02\test-level2.doc
```

**Update 2**

A prefix `**/` may be added to the `PathMatcher` to cross directory boundaries, then `Files.walk`-based solution may use simplified filter without the need to remove specific entries:

```java
String mask = "*.doc*";
PathMatcher maskMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**/" + mask);
Files.walk(Paths.get(SOURCE_DIR))
     .filter(path -> maskMatcher.matches(path))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output (same as in the recursive solution):

```
test\level01\level11\test.doc
test\level02\test-level2.doc
test\t1.doc
test\t3.docx
```

Comment: "with appropriate regular expression", well... that is a problem, I don't want to have to deal with regular expressions, I want the file mask that user inputs to work right away. I mentioned the "*.doc" example but that's it not the only file mask that can be used, with this, I will have to convert every single one to a proper regular expression.

Comment: added recursive solution using common file mask